# Can I create an Outlook contact group for everyone I've ever sent an email to?

Tags: mac, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

I use Outlook for Mac at work (I don't remember which version) and Outlook 365 when I'm working from home.  I would like to create a contact group of everyone I've ever sent an email to, but I don't know if that's possible outside of going through months of emails and copying everything manually.  Is there a way to do this in bulk?  Thanks!

Comment: I think you would need to adapt / write a VBA to do this. I do not know of any native way to go through all sent emails

Comment: Sadly, neither Outlook for Mac nor the web version supports VBA.

Comment: I do not know any other way so you will have to add Contacts you need over time. Set a target of 10 to 15 per day until done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it's not feasible from either Outlook for Mac or Outlook on the Web.

If you have access to Outlook for Windows, however, you can export mails in Sent Items folder to CSV file in order to get a list of the all the recipients' email addresses, and then create a contact group using the Excel list.

In Outlook for Mac, you may have to create the contact group manually over time.